# How to calculate return value from select statement in T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a T-SQL stored procedure with a couple of select statements (which are output of the SP, so they must be there). But the SP is also returning a value.

How can I have there select statements and at the same time return a value depending on what is in the result of these select statements?

One solution would be to create a temp table, select into it. Then query the table for a result and select * from the temp table.

But is there simpler solution that that?
Thanks, Radek

Comment: It depends on your select statements. Is the structure of all your selects the same?

Comment: Are you aware of output parameters? Would one or more of those meet your requirements?

Comment: I would also suggest an output parameter.

Comment: My question was not about the output of the SP but the output of the select statement that could be used to return e.g. an error code depending on what rows where returned by previous SELECT.